# Android keep alive IntentService

Tags: android, multithreading, sockets, service, background

I need to keep alive a thread which allows me to send data, even if the app is in background or killed (the user slide the app away or close it).

I know I could use Service or IntentService. Someone told me that with IntentService I can use notification, what I am doing is something like app such as Telegram or Whatsapp which listens continuously for new messages.

I used **Service** and this is my result :

```
package test.com.connectionservices.Services;


import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;

public class UDPListenerService extends Service {
    static String UDP_BROADCAST = "UDPBroadcast";

    DatagramSocket socket;

    private void listenAndWaitAndThrowIntent() throws Exception {
        try {
            DatagramSocket clientSocket = null;
            clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();
            String data ;
            byte[] sendData ;
            InetAddress IPAddress = InetAddress.getByName("AN IP");

            int i = 0;
                while (true) {
                data = "TEST THE SERVICE"+i;
                sendData = data.getBytes();
                DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, 21);
                clientSocket.send(sendPacket);
                i++;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

    private void broadcastIntent(String senderIP, String message) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(UDPListenerService.UDP_BROADCAST);
        intent.putExtra("sender", senderIP);
        intent.putExtra("message", message);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    Thread UDPBroadcastThread;

    void startListenForUDPBroadcast() {
        UDPBroadcastThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    while (shouldRestartSocketListen) {
                        listenAndWaitAndThrowIntent();
                    }
                    //if (!shouldListenForUDPBroadcast) throw new ThreadDeath();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.i("UDP", "no longer listening for UDP broadcasts cause of error " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
        UDPBroadcastThread.start();
    }

    private Boolean shouldRestartSocketListen = true;

    void stopListen() {
        shouldRestartSocketListen = false;
        socket.close();
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        stopListen();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        shouldRestartSocketListen = true;
        startListenForUDPBroadcast();
        Log.i("UDP", "Service started");
        return START_STICKY;
    }
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

This works fine, if I go in another app or I kill the app using Android (sliding it away in Lollipop) there will be a process in background which flood the reciver.

How could I change it using IntentService? Why should I change, is there a way to use notification with Service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason for you to use `IntentService` here. `IntentService` queues the start commands it receives (from calls to `startService()`) and executes them serially on a background thread, then stops itself when the queue is depleted. That's not the behavior you want, so don't use it.

To use the service with a notification, use the [`startForeground()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground(int,%20android.app.Notification)) method and provide a Notification object to show. I wouldn't recommend this except for something that should be visible to the user, like a music playback service (with playback controls in the notification).